# C# ready to use structure that holds two integers

Tags: c#, types

In .Net is there a ready to use structure that holds two integers (like Point)?

Comment: You mean like `System.Drawing.Point` or `System.Windows.Point`? Why not ask a search engine?

Comment: `Tuple<int, int>`

Comment: @Tim, `Tuple<>` is a reference type -- a `class`, not a `struct`.

Comment: `Tuple`, `Point` or even `int[2]`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm guessing OP means structure to mean "any sort of object" rather than a struct.

Comment: @David, maybe. I may have read too much into the terminology.

Comment: What is the problem with creating one - or do you expect it to have particular methods, properties etc

Comment: If he really needs a struct, I think Point is the one to use I don't think the Tuple is a struct. Point exists in System.Windows and in System.Drawing depends on which type of environment you use (first is for WPF or XAML apps, second for Windows Forms)

Comment: I don't know what your argument is for not creating one, but I would. Could just call it "Int2".

Comment: He could create a struct with one Tuple-Property ... :-P

Comment: it was good if you tell us the reason. if you just want 2 int then create an array or a simple struct. dont make your code ugly with using unnecessary classes. they are made for a reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various.

- `System.Drawing.Point` which has a dependency on WinForms (System.Drawing.dll)

Downside: you need to reference WPF's dlls

- `System.Windows.Point` which has a dependency or WPF (WindowsBase.dll)

Downside: you need to reference WinForms's dlls

- [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) Which can hold a series of values of any type.

Downside: Working with its properties is not exactly intuitive and not possible to document, as it is basically just addressed by `tupleObject.Item1` and `tupleObject.Item2`.

Bottomline, if you don't want to deal with any of those downsides, you might as well create your own class

Comment: downside for all of them... unnecessary complexity of code

Comment: Isn't `System.Drawing.Point` in WinForms and `System.Windows.Point` in WPF?  I think you may have those backwards.

Comment: ooh, absolutely, Chris. I messed up my copy paste :P

I edited my answer, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Tuple< int, int >](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.

Example:

```
var data = new Tuple<int, int>(1, 10);

// to get data
var x = data.Item1;
var y = data.Item2;
```

> A tuple is a data structure that has a specific number and sequence of
>   elements. An example of a tuple is a data structure with three
>   elements (known as a 3-tuple or triple) that is used to store an
>   identifier such as a person's name in the first element, a year in the
>   second element, and the person's income for that year in the third
>   element. The .NET Framework directly supports tuples with one to seven
>   elements. In addition, you can create tuples of eight or more elements
>   by nesting tuple objects in the Rest property of a Tuple object.

Comment: I don't like tuples at all, except for very specific circumstances. They give rise to unreadable code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I for one don't share your opinion, find them more useful than obfuscating

Comment: @KarmaEDV Well, (a) you can't add XML comments to tuple properties to indicate what they mean and (b) they are always called `Item1` and `Item2` etc. Definitely not something to use for returning non-generic values from a public interface, IMO.

Comment: @MatthewWatson agreed on that use case!

Answer (score 2):

Just examples...

```
var tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2);
var array = new int[2] {1, 2};
```